# woocommerce different prices based in weight

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

It is posible in woocommerce to create different prices based in weight to display in a select dropdown?

For example:

food for dogs: 
    5k = $20
    10k = $40
    20k = $60

Comment: refer this link https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Answer (score 6):

It is possible in WooCommerce to create different prices based on weight -

In Variable products in WooCommerce that lets you offer a set of variations on a product, with control over prices, stock, image and more for each variation.

**Step 1- Set the product type**

- Go to: **WooCommerce > Products**.
- Select the **Add Product** button or Edit an existing product. The Product Data displays.
- Select **Variable product** from the Product Data dropdown.

  [image]

**Step 2- Add attribute.**

- Go to : **Products > Attributes**
- Then give name attribute.
- Save.

[image]

- Then select on weight attribute.
- Add sub-attribute in weight attribute (5k,10k,15k).

[image]

**Step 3- Add attributes to use for variations**

- Go to : **Products**
- Then select product **you set as variable product in step 1**
- Select **Attributes then select Custom product attribute**(that is weight), and **Add**.
- In weight **select sub-attribute**.
- Then **Select check box used** for variation.
- Save attribute.

[image]

**Step 4. Add variations**

- Goto:**Variations Select Add variation** from the drop-down menu, and click Go
- **Select attributes for your variation**. To change additional data, **click the triangle icon** to expand the variation.
- **Edit Price for each attribute**.
- **Save Changes**.

[image]

> **Read more:** https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/
>
> **Watch this Video**- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUcAf89LfCc
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aen8ieJuB88

Comment: plus one for the effort of answering in detail

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Go to product edit page, for which you like to set prices based on weight.

**Step 2:** Select ***Product Type*** as a ***variable product***, see the image below. Create product attribute, save the attribute. I named the attribute ***weight*** .

See the image below:

[image: Capture.png]

**Step 3:** Now we need to add product variation, see the image below:

[image: 2Capture.png]

**Step 4:** For each of these variation, u can set any prices you want, see the image below

[image: Edit Product ‹ Classique Floors & tile — WordPre.png]

**Step 5:** update the product, that's it.